# What is the probability that exactly two of three people have a birthday in the same month?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $3$ people.What is the probability that exactly two of them have birthday in same month?
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Any thoughts?  You need to clarify if you mean "at least two" or "exactly two" and, of course, you should indicate whether or not you are assuming that each month is equally probable.

Comment: it depends from month, some of them have different number of days. but if you define $30$ days as a mean, so Bernoulli formula will define your prob.

Comment: How many triples $(a,b,c)$ can be written using the numbers from $1$ to $30$? In how many of those the numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$ are all distinct?

Comment: What have you tried?  Please add your attempts to solve it on your own.  Where exactly did you get stuck (and commenting "I have no clue" doesn't count as effort.")  This looks like a run-of-the-mill problem statement that you expect us, to solve, for you.  Unfortunately, this is not a "do-everything-for-me, i.e. solve it for me" site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are assuming that the birthdays are uniformly distributed in the $12$ months this is my hint.

The probability  that they are all in different months is
$$p_1=\frac{12\cdot 11\cdot 10}{12^3}.$$
The probability  that they are all in the same month is
$$p_2=\frac{12}{12^3}.$$
So what is the probability that exactly two of them have birthday in the same month?

Comment: No worries, Robert.  I see your edit.  Sometimes I get frustrated when an asker never clarifies what, exactly, they are assuming, and answerers proceed to guess at what is meant.  (I simply wish, that unless the asker clarifies, no guess would be made, and no answer provided until the asker responds to comments, or answers.)  My issue is primarily with the asker, not you.  I appreciate your edit, and I have deleted my initial comment.

Comment: @amWhy Now, I get it. Thanks.

Comment: @amWhy this same question was asked in an exam.Now what else should be clarified? Is this question so ambigous?

Comment: @RobertZ will it be  $3C2 * p_2$ ?

Comment: @RobertZ i didnt understand

Comment: @nrb If it is not true that just 2 of the 3 people have birthday in the same month then they are all in different months or they are all in the same month. So the probabilty is equal to...

Comment: @RobertZ the probability will be $1-p1-p2$...you are such a great teacher Robert.

Comment: @nrb Very well!!

Answer (score 1):

$\underline{Hint}$

Since you have specified *exactly* two,

- The "duo" can be chosen in $\binom32$ ways
- They can be born in any of the $12$ months
- The "single" now has $11$ choices of month

Taking the probability of being born in any month as equi-probable,

can you now compute the required probability ?